# Examples when space between C++ or C operators must not be removed

Tags: c++, c, operators, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to come up with all examples when removing whitespace between operators in valid C or C++ code changes its meaning (by changing it to code which does something else or which doesn't compile).

I enumerated http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++ and I could come up with:

`+ +`:

```
int f(int a) { return a + /**/ +5; }
```

`- -`:

```
int f(int a) { return a - /**/ -5; }
```

I was trying `1& &p` as well, but I couldn't make it compile with a space, I always got type errors.

I'm looking for answers in the following format: a valid C or C++ code snippet with `/**/` and spaces between two operators (see two examples above). The removal of `/**/` and the surrounding whitespace must produce a compile error or change the meaning of the compiled program.

Some context why I need it: I'm writing a C and C++ source translator which removes unnecessary whitespace. To make it correct, I need to understand when whitespace can't be removed without changing the meaning of the code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is polling.


Comment: I don't get it. All of the changes you mention make them different operators.

Comment: it's a yes no question. furthermore it asks for plain facts. neither of those properties are compatible with the polling hypothesis

Comment: What kind of question is this _"So is there any other case (apart from + + and - -) where the whitespace is significant"_  Don't you think this is in very first chapters of a C/C++ book ?

Comment: The best way I can think of to answer this is to take all of the two-character operators and put spaces in the middle.

Comment: @P0W: not at all. i don't know of any textbook that addresses this question. what kind of question is that.

Comment: @chris: no that won't work. e.g. `x < < 3` will just not compile.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Please come up with list of all such cases, I'll upvote

Comment: Can you guys explain what's wrong with this question as a SO question? I don't see any poll or yes/no properties and also find it somewhat interesting. Who is a brave enough to write a script to generate tests for all operator cases? ;)

Comment: @POW: regarding "please come up with a list of all such cases" in response to me, I **have not** talked about a list of cases. Your statement is pure trolling. I mean, since you know that it is nonsense, and know that it's misleading.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oh the sarcasm. :P

Comment: @Drop, surely I'm not, but what's the use of it, just to prove  _"I have not failed. I've just found 10000 ways that won't work."_

Comment: @Drop "it's a yes/no question" was sarcasm. The post ends with "is there ...?", which was meant to signify "please enumerate more of them" by OP, but the grammar was exploited by Cheers Alf in a sarcastic manner, suggesting that this question is not suited for SO. And as to your question: this post is not a good fit here because it asks for simply enumerating overly general things instead of asking about **one**, **specific** problem.

Comment: @P0W I don't see any uses. We also have a [SE site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) full of such useless stuff. Someone really like it.

Comment: @Drop Yeah that's nice site

Comment: @H2CO3: If you want one, specific problem: I'm writing a C and C++ source translator which removes unnecessary whitespace. To make it correct, I need to understand when whitespace can't be removed without changing the meaning of the code. I was not asking a broader question, because I can sort out other subtopics alone, I need advice only on this one I asked. I've just added this info to the question.

Comment: @pts Well, that's definitely better. Now you can't just decide whether or not remove whitespace by looking at operators. You will have to write a C (C++?) parser that understands the syntax.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm pretty sure I have to write a tokenizer. How much of a real parser I have to write is about to be designed. For example, I can play it safe by not removing whitespace in preprocessor directives, between identifiers (e.g. `void f`) and some operators (e.g. `+ +`), and removing whitespace everywhere else.

Comment: For those who voted *unclear what you are asking*, could you please advise how I can make the question more clear? What is ambiguous in it? How is it unclear what kind of answers I'm looking for? (I've given 2 examples, I'm looking for more like that.)

Comment: Any operator that contains 2 characters, from `||` to `--`, is an operator where a space more or a space less in between changes the meaning. I don't really get the hype of this question. Also, spaces between operators are not the only things that you need to worry about.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Not compiling was part of the main post as an option.

Comment: @chris: oh you're right. i didn't notice, because that makes it a meaningless question. thanks.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Your example `| |` is not a valid answer to my question, because it cannot be part of valid C or C++ code. I not looking for all possible code snippets when an extra space makes a difference. I'm looking for valid C or C++ code where _removing_ a space makes a difference. (Please read all the details in the question.) If you know of related topics to worry about, please share them with us.

Comment: I've added more details to the question. It's not true anymore that there are too many possible answers: there is no evidence that there is anything else than ++, --, &&, >>, trigraphs and digraphs (and I'd like to get the help of others to find out if there is). It's not true anymore that good answers would be too long, because a good answer consists only of a short C or C++ code snippet, most probably a one-liner. Please reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example to serve as a sort of proof that your examples are not the only ones.  But surely there are plenty more that can be created, so I won't try to enumerate them.

```
#include <cassert>

struct C {
    operator bool() const { return true; }
};

bool operator&(C& l, C* r) { return false; }

int main()
{
    C a, b;
    assert(a &&b); // or put space between &&
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I learned from this answer that it's easy to get rid of type errors by operator overloading.

Comment: @pts, that's not really the intended takeaway.  And I hope for the sake of everyone that you don't actually mean to use that. :X

Comment: *Surely there are plenty more*: my intuition says otherwise, I think there are no more. If you have the time, could you please come up with at least one more?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: This is a very relevant and intended takeaway for the purposes of this question. For other purposes (such as writing correct and maintainable C++ code), it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 3):

In order to fully answer or understand this question, you need to understand how C++ tokenizing and parsing works.

Here's what's required for this to work.  Some multicharacter token, which can be cut into smaller tokens, after that, you just have to come up with a good way to figure out how to make it compile.

Let's start at the beginning, trigraph sequences:

```
Table 1 — Trigraph sequences
??= #    ??( [    ??< {
??/ \    ??) ]    ??> }
??' ˆ    ??! |    ??- ∼
```

The question mark, also doubles as the conditional operator, cannot normally be doubled up in the language.  However, there are a few places where a doubled question mark can be valid, inside of string literal, for instance, or inside of the d-char-sequence of a raw string literal.  So we can actually construct an example where removing part of a trigraph completely alters how a line is parsed.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const char* asdf  = "?? /"; std::cout << R";//"(content);//"" << std::endl;
  const char* asdf2 = "??/"; std::cout << R";//"(content);//"" << std::endl;
  std::cout << asdf  << std::endl;
  std::cout << asdf2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, because there's so few places you can shoehorn in a `??` or a `? ?` the possibilities are is a bit limited. (Which is one of the reasons why `??` sequences were chosen for the trigraph, there is very little valid C++ code that features them, and legacy is important to the committee.)  I could go on from here.  Trigraphs are probably the most challenging example.  But I'll leave the rest as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning trigraphs. I'll have to take a look at splitting both digraphs and trigraphs.

Comment: Trigraphs are a nice example since they apply to C, too. The others (mine for `<>` or for having an implicit conversion) are only C++.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there is (or was) the notorious problem of `<>` being comparison operator and template brackets. There are (or have been) cases where whitespace changes the semantic, but doesn't necessarily lead to a compile time error. Examples for that are quite involved, I once have written up such a case [here](http://parxxl.gforge.inria.fr/doxymentation/CodingStyle.html):

```
template< int len > int fun(int x);
typedef int (*fun_t)(int);
template< fun_t f > int fon(int x);

void total(void) {
   int A = fon< fun< 9 > >(1) >>(2);
   int B = fon< fun< 9 >>(1) > >(2);
}
```

For A we take the function `fon` that depends on function pointer `fun<9>` and call that with argument `1`. The result is then shifted by `2` to the right.

In contrast, for `B` we call the function `fon` that depends on function pointer `fun<5>` and pass it the argument `2`. (The `5` is the result of shifting `9` by one to the right.)

So just because of some blanks are spread differently the result can be completely different.

All of this might have changed with C++11, where the rules for template parameter `<>` have been modified.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is "no, there are no further cases" where code that compiles changes meaning because of a space within the characters of an operator,  but I would have to carefully enumerate all operators and use cases before saying I'm sure.

One thing is for sure, the comments about how easy this question is, are best ignored.